# How can I deal with offline message with Xmpp on iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp

The situation is below: 
I have an iOS app with chat functionality(one on one chat) by using xmpp. If one user's app is offline accidentally, our xmpp server won't recognize that the user has been offline until, let's say, two minutes later(too frequent check will cause server crash). And in this two minutes, if there are messages coming, how can I receive those messages?

My concern is that since the server still think the user is online, it will still deal with those messages as usual messages. What should I do now?

Comment: In xmpp, if user app is offline still it maintains persistent connection to server ?

Comment: nope, it disconnects

Comment: If it disconnects then i don't think server should treat that user as online.If it is then it is a bug on server side.If your is offline then server may store messages on it then send it when user becomes online.

Comment: the server needs time to recognize the app has been already offline, during this period of time, if messages come, I have no idea how to receive the messages.

Comment: In XMPP, there will be persistent connection and if it breaks server will immediately know that, i  don't see any reason why server takes that much time to detect it.There is a problem on server side i don't think you can fix it from client side.

Comment: Could you please tell a bit more about the detail of persistent connection in XMPP because currently our server side can't detect that immediately. Any protocol or code to describe this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155298/discussion-between-girdhar-sojitra-and-otakufitness).